# Multipath Propagation Correction for LTE signals

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, lte, localization

How can I correct multipath propagation for LTE signals generated from different eNodeBs?

My end goal is to implement localization of my USRP using LTE or FM signals. Currently I am carrying out a few simulations (in MATLAB) to test the TOA/TDOA algorithm. I have added several different impairments to my Downlink RMC waveforms (AWGN, I/Q Imbalance, Multipath Effect and etc.) which are generated from three different base stations around my USRP. I have tested these different impairments and the algorithm is robust to all of them except the multipath effect. So what algorithm/method can I use to minimize the effect of multipath propagation? I know I cannot use Equalization algorithms in OFDM systems so what other options do I have?

Any suggestions/resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how you estimate the TOA, but you need to estimate the first path, not the strongest path. For example, https://patents.justia.com/patent/11428774 Note that I have never worked on this issue, then let us know if you nail it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I correct multipath propagation

that **is** called *equalization*! So, you'll *have* to do that, even if you claim you can't.

> for LTE signals generated from different eNodeBs?

That's the whole idea of using OFDM in LTE: You decompose the wideband channel, in which you see the path differences between direct paths and reflected paths as complex channel impulse reponse, to orthogonal narrowband channels, which are then narrow enough so that you only observe the channel (per subcarrier) as a single complex number. You invert that number.

So, you build the physical layer receiver for LTE, and then that's inherently solved by OFDM.